CDK only deploy first stack - getting "No stacks match the name(s)" for others
I'm running into a weird issue with CDK. I have three envs for a services, defined as stacks. I have previously deployed all three of them (each in an individual account). Each stack shows up in CloudFormation.
I can deploy the first stack fine (cdk deploy myapp-service-development). However when I run cdk deploy myapp-service-test I'm getting the error No stacks match the name(s) myapp-service-test. When I comment the first stack (developemt) out, I can deploy the next stack (test) and so on.
The command cdk ls only ever gives me the first stack defined in the file below:
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { devEnv, testEnv, prodEnv } from "@my-app/configuration";
import { MyStack } from "../src/infrastructure/index.js";
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";

const app = new cdk.App();

new MyStack(app, `myapp-service-development`, {
  stackName: "service",
  env: devEnv, // this is { account: "someAccountId", region: "eu-central-1"}
});

new MyStack(app, "myapp-service-test", {
  stackName: "service",
  env: testEnv,
});

new MyStack(app, `myapp-service-production`, {
  stackName: "service",
  env: prodEnv,
});




When you run cdk deploy myapp-service-test, how are you specifying that you want to use credentials for the test env? I set up an app using your code. When I run npx cdk --profile=<dev profile> --region=<dev region> deploy myapp-service-development, npx cdk --profile=<test profile> --region=<test region> deploy myapp-service-test, and npx cdk --profile=<prod profile> --region=<prod region> deploy myapp-service-prod, it all works as expected, on initial and subsequent deploys. npx cdk ls works as expected, too, listing all stacks.

This could be a limitation in CDK due to the fact that all of your stacks have the same name.

@DougNaphas Honestly, no idea why it started behaving like this. I have other services in the monorepo with the same setup that work perfectly fine. I specify the credentials like you do. I have found a workaround at the moment, that I post

This is my current workaround which let me deploys the individual stacks.
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { devEnv, testEnv, prodEnv } from "@my-app/configuration";
import { MyStack } from "../src/infrastructure/index.js";
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";

const app = new cdk.App();

const bundlingStacks = app.node.tryGetContext("aws:cdk:bundling-stacks") as Array<string>;
const buildAllStacks = bundlingStacks.includes("**");

if (buildAllStacks || bundlingStacks.includes(`easypliant-${serviceName}-development`)) {
  new MyStack(app, `myapp-service-development`, {
    stackName: "service",
    env: devEnv, // this is { account: "someAccountId", region: "eu-central-1"}
  });
}

if (buildAllStacks || bundlingStacks.includes(`easypliant-${serviceName}-test`)) {
  new MyStack(app, "myapp-service-test", {
    stackName: "service",
    env: testEnv,
  });
}

if (buildAllStacks || bundlingStacks.includes(`easypliant-${serviceName}-production`)) {
  new MyStack(app, `myapp-service-production`, {
    stackName: "service",
    env: prodEnv,
  });
}


